# Why are some typeclasses prefixed with "Monad"?

Tags: haskell, monads

Reading through some code I sometimes come across typeclasses that are prefixed with `Monad`, examples of these are `MonadState`, `MonadIO`, `MonadReader`, etc.

What exactly is the purpose of these?

Taking `MonadState` as an example, I know that

- `State` allows stateless state
- `StateT` allows the use of other monads, like `IO` to *"combine"* the functionality of both

But `MonadState` allows what exactly?

I don't get the need for another group of similarly named types/typeclasses, can someone explain?

Comment: I think this is more a question about the design of [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) (right?) - why the naming conventions are that way seems to be a bit opinionated to me ...

Comment: Because they're subclasses of monads! `class (Monad m) => MonadXYZ m where ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`State`, `StateT` and other types like them come from [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers), while the `MonadState` typeclass and other typeclasses like it come from [`mtl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl). Notice that the former are *types*, while the latter are *typeclasses*.

The types from `transformers` are instances of `Monad` and `MonadTrans`. You can work directly with them, but there are a couple of annoyances:

- If you have a monad stack several layers deep, you have to sprinkle your code with a lot of calls to `lift` in order to access the functionality of each layer.
- Sometimes two different types provide the same "interface". For example, both `RWST` and `ReaderT` offer reader-like functionality like `ask`. When writing a function, it is annoying to have to commit to one of the other, as it reduces generality.

The `Monad*` typeclasses from `mtl` alleviate these problems:

- They have "pass-through" instances that eliminate many calls to `lift` (or, more precisely, handle them automatically). For example, `StateT` is an instance of `MonadState`, but a `ReaderT` over `StateT` is also an instance of `MonadState`, so you can use `get` directly.

  ```
  import Control.Monad
  import Control.Monad.Reader
  import Control.Monad.State

  -- put the environment in the state
  bar :: ReaderT Int (State Int) ()
  bar = ask >>= lift . put -- we use lift here

  barMTL :: ReaderT Int (State Int) ()
  -- This ONLY works if we have imported the 
  -- required instances from mtl.
  -- The MonadState instance for ReaderT, in particular.
  barMTL = ask >>= put -- the put is auto-lifted
  ```
- You can put a `Monad*` constraint in your functions and work against the `Monad*` "interface" instead of committing right away to a specific implementation of the monad. This way your functions become more general and choosing the exact "implementation" is delayed to the last possible moment.

  ```
  import Control.Monad
  import Control.Monad.State
  import Control.Monad.RWS

  -- Dumb function that increments the state.
  -- Doesn't commit to a specific implementation of the monad.
  baz :: MonadState Int m => m ()
  baz = modify succ

  main :: IO ()
  main = do
      -- run as State
      print $ runState baz 0 
      -- run as RWS
      print $ runRWS (baz >> tell ()) () 0
  ```

Comment: could you provide some example code of `Monad*` typeclasses in action?

Comment: there is a really nice [**tutorial**](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf) for this

Comment: @Carsten The tutorial doesn't cover the `mtl`, though.

Comment: I think I get it, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Electric Coffee Here's a possible exercise: write a function that asks for the reader environment, multiplies it with the current state, and stores the result in a "log". It should work with a `ReaderT Int (WriterT [Int] (State Int)) ()` monad stack as well as `RWS Int [Int] Int ()`.

Comment: @danidiaz, there is a tutorial covering mtl, called something like "Monad Transformers Step by Step". It does quite a good job of showing how seductive the typeclass approach can be.

Answer (score 2):

`MonadState` is not a monad, but is a subclass of `Monad`. `State` is a monad (and also a `MonadState`). The monad subclass `MonadState` is used to make functions such as `get`,`put` work on any monad which has a notion of a gettable/settable "state".

Comment: I wasn't talking about `MonadState` specifically, but any class with the `Monad` prefix. I just used `MonadState` as an arbitrary example

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The same goes for `MonadReader`, `MonadIO`, `MonadError`, etc.  Each of these is a typeclass, not a type.  These are provided so that you can have more generic functions than just `StateT` allows.  You could even define your own instance of `MonadState` (or any of the others) as you need.  They're available to keep you from being tied down to just `StateT` or `ReaderT` or `IO` or whatever.

Comment: Could you give an example?